# terraform aws_lb_listener_rule condition arguement not getting recognized in terraform 0.12.20

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

getting this error in aws_lb_listener_rule

Error: Unsupported argument

on ....\euc-terraformcontrol-alb\alb.tf line 127, in resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "alb_listener_rule":
127:     field            = "${element(split(",", var.listener_rule_field), count.index)}"

An argument named "field" is not expected here.

Error: Unsupported argument

on ....\euc-terraformcontrol-alb\alb.tf line 128, in resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "alb_listener_rule":
128:     values           = ["${element(split(",", var.listener_rule_value), count.index)}"]

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "alb_listener_rule" {
  count              = "${length(compact(split(",", var.priority))) > 0 ? "${length(compact(split(",", var.priority)))}" : 0}"
  listener_arn       = "${var.listener_arn}"
  priority           = "${element(split(",", var.priority), count.index)}"
  action              {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${element(split(",", var.target_group_arn), count.index)}"
  }
  condition           {
    //field            = "${element(split(",", var.listener_rule_field), count.index)}"
    //values           = "${element(split(",", var.listener_rule_value), count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is breaking changes in the [new version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-3-upgrade#resource-aws_lb_listener_rule)

In the older version, we were able to use below code for conditional routing

```
 condition {
   field = "host-header"
   values = ["api.example.com"]
 }
```

Switch your Terraform configuration to use the `host_header` or `path_pattern` **configuration block** instead.

So the above condition will become

```
   condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["api.example.com"]
    }
  }
```

If you are running you code in some CI/CD platform then better to add a version in configuration to avoid such issue in future and keep the code compatible.

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.31.0"
}
```

> The version `meta-argument` specifies a version constraint for a `provider`, and works the same way as the version argument in a required_providers block. The version constraint in a provider configuration is only used if required_providers does not include one for that provider.

[/provider-veriosing](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/provider-requirements.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `field` and `values` were **deprecated** in aws provider version 2.x as shown [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.64.0/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule#condition-blocks). In the provider version 3.x they are  removed and **no longer valid** as shown in the new docs for [condition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule#condition-blocks) block.

This is further explained in the official "Terraform AWS Provider Version 3 Upgrade Guide" in:

- [condition.field and condition.values Arguments Removal](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-3-upgrade#resource-aws_lb_listener_rule)

So you either have to migrate your code to work with aws provider 3.x or go back to using older version.